# How to have a notification for reaching critical and reorder levels

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, forms

I need to create a part of a program where in its inventory and reaches reorder level which is the first warning for buying stocks as it reaches the set reorder level for a certain item. And if it reaches the critical level, it would also have a notification warning to buy needed stocks in inventory.

Things to consider:
- Each of our item has different reorder and critical levels since we have it as one part of the item data in our database.
- The data is shown in a data grid view.
- I am using c# windows form and sql server as its connected database

Comment: What does a notification imply? You want to log it? Email it? Pop up a message box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set your variables, keep in mind you didn't show any code so mine is pseudo.

```
int reorder=35;
int critical=25;    
boolean shownWarning=false;    
int inStock =50;
```

this you will want to check whenever your quantities change. I.E. you sell an item.

the first one uses and integer set to the "reorder level" and a boolean to display only once a warning to buy more.

```
 if(inStock<=reorder&&!shownWarning){
    MessageBox.Show("please Order More Stock.");
    shownWarning=true;
    }
```

the second method gets desperate and ditches the bool and tells you every time you sell an item to order more.

```
   if(inStock<=critical){
    MessageBox.Show("Supply Limited. please Order More Stock.");
    }
```

if you use this method, when you do reorder, and adjust your stock, you will need to reset the bool to false, so it catches it the next go round.

Comment: I think this is the closest one that I can get, but the critical and reorder level is from the database data, and  the items have a different set of critical and reorder which makes it complicated since it needs to read each item's critical and reorder.